# Plotting confidence interval by group with ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot confidence intervals with shadow bands by groups in R. The ideal case is that the color of all bands stays the same (grey). I made some typos in ggplot2 and it somehow generates the plot I was expecting. While after correcting the typos, I could never get the plot I want. Could anyone explain what is going on here.

### simulated data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(educ = rep(c("level 1","level 2","level 3"),each = 10),
                  age = 65:69,value = c(seq(1,5,by=1),seq(1,5,by=1)-1,
                                        seq(5,9,by=1),seq(5,9,by=1)-1,
                                        seq(10,14,by=1),seq(10,14,by=1)-1),
                  sd = abs(rnorm(30)/10),
                  educ_child = rep(rep(c("HS","HS and above"),each= 5),3))
```

### These codes generate what I want, but there is an improper argument name (aaaaa) in `geom_ribbon` and a warning message.

```
ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = age,y=value,color = educ,linetype=educ_child))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value-1.96*sd,
                  ymax = value+1.96*sd,aaaaa=educ_child,linetype=NA),alpha = .2)+
  theme_light()
```

The warning message is:

Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: aaaaa

[image: The plot I do want (but the argument name is wrong)]

### After removing this argument, there is an error message and no plot is generated

```
ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = age,y=value,color = educ,linetype=educ_child))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value-1.96*sd,
                  ymax = value+1.96*sd,group=educ_child,linetype=NA),alpha = .2)+
  theme_light()
```

the error message is:

Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

### After correcting this argument name to a reasonable one, the figure went wrong

```
ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = age,y=value,color = educ,linetype=educ_child))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value-1.96*sd,
                  ymax = value+1.96*sd,linetype=NA),alpha = .2)+
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `group` aesthetic should be the interaction between `educ` and `educ_child`, since there are separate ribbons for each subset within both of these variables:

```r
ggplot(dat,
       aes(x = age, y = value, color = educ, linetype = educ_child)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value - 1.96 * sd,
                  ymax = value + 1.96 * sd, 
                  group = interaction(educ, educ_child), linetype = NA),
              alpha = 0.2)+
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes, these codes work! Yet I am still confused about why typing in the improper argument also works and somehow generates the thing I want. Will `ggplot` make some inference automatically?